# How to find google play service version in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am trying to use google play services for location purposes. Therefore I wanted to add google play services to my app. In build.gradle dependincies I added following line.

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
```

However it gives following error

```
 Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1
```

I couldnt find which version of Google play services installed. In SDK Tools tab it says version 30.

I've tried following line too but it also gave same error

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:30'
```

Edit: Here is the whole build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ozu.cs394.umurali.whereismycar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
}
```

Comment: which version of SDK tools do you have?

Comment: I have SDK Tools 25.1.6

Comment: can you post your `build.gradle` (app) file

Comment: Okay, I posted it.

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project? Build -> Clean Project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should update google play services repository in `sdk manager`:

[image]

Comment: There are instances where one would need to know the exact verison number. Like when using `react-native-geo-location-service` [https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service] In that case the sdk manager showed me `version` as `49` which is incorrect and I suggest following `pm dubey`'s answer to get what you need.

Answer (score 19):

- Go to File -> Project Structure
- Select 'Project Settings'
- Select 'Dependencies' Tab
- Click '+' and select '1.Library Dependencies'
- Search for : `com.google.android.gms:play-services`
- Select the latest version and click 'OK'

Comment: Best answer ever

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i could now add my installed libs without touching gradle files, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK Manager under Extras and make sure that `Google Repository` is installed.