# @integer/google_play_services_version in play-services-15.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

Does anybody know what is the number of `google_play_services_version` in `play-services-15.0.0.`? 

 Regards

Comment: just google this LMFGTFY, it might help

Comment: There is a good procedure in this post for upgrading from Android Studio [Dependency Upgrade Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545147/how-to-find-google-play-service-version-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Elletlar I have updated it already but last available version after update in my sdk folder is 11.0.4.

Comment: @A_P I am googling about three days but could not  set @integer/google_play_services_version in play-services-15.0.0 resolved.